# Why is my Python code jumping from one function into another that I didn't call?

Tags: python, function

My program creates a `list` of stations, with some information about them. I have three `edit` functions set up: `edit_mp ()`, `edit_name ()` and `edit_clear ()`. These three can only be called from a menu at the beginning of the `edit_station ()` function. `edit_mp ()` is currently taking user input and then jumps into the middle of the `edit_clear ()`.

I have two types of objects: a `Station` object which stores some information and a `Subdivision` object which stores the list of stations and a sorted list of one feature of those stations.

I tried adding extra checks into the function, which has demonstrated that the function stops right after the `"New milepost is"`-line and confirming the `input.upper ()`. It should move on to the `if-else-loop` immediately, but the `print` statements I put into the `if` are not working and the `else` doesn't call `edit_station_menu ()`. Instead, I get the `"Please enter a whole number"` statement and the siding length prompt from `edit_clear ()`.

```
def edit_station():
    global n
    global mp_edit
    n = 0
    mp_edit = input("Enter milepost of station to edit.")
    while n <= len(sub_list[i].stations):
        if sub_list[i].stations[n].mp == float(mp_edit):
            edit_station_menu()
        elif n < len(sub_list[i].stations):
            n += 1
        else:
            print("Milepost not found.  Enter 1 to try again, or any other key to return.")
            choice = input()
            if choice == "1":
                edit_station()
            else:
                display_sub()

def edit_station_menu():
    global n
    global mp_edit
    sta = sub_list[i].stations[n]
    def edit_mp():
        print("STATION SELECTED: " + sta.name)
        mp = input("Station milepost: ")
        try:
            mp = float(mp)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid milepost number (numerals and decimals only).")
            edit_mp()
        else:
            print("New milepost is " + str(mp) + ". Is this correct? Y/N")
            correct = input()
            if correct.upper() == "Y":
                sub_list[i].mp.remove(mp_edit)
                print("Original milepost removed.")
                sta.mp = mp
                sub_list[i].mp.append(sta.mp)
                print("New milepost added.")
                if sub_list[i].ascend_dir == "W" or sub_list[i].ascend_dir == "S":
                    sub_list[i].mp.sort()
                else:
                    sub_list[i].mp.sort()
                    sub_list[i].mp.reverse()
                edit_station_menu()
            else:
                print("Ready to move on, nothing has changed.")
                input()
                edit_mp()

    def edit_name():
        print("STATION SELECTED: " + sta.name)
        name = input("Enter new station name: ").upper()
        print("New station name is " + name + ". Is this correct? Y/N")
        correct = input()
        if correct.upper() == "Y":
            sta.name = name
            edit_station_menu()
        else:
            edit_name()

    def edit_clear():
        def edit_sdglen():
            sdglen = input("Enter siding length: ")
            try:
                sta.sdglen = int(sdglen)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a whole number.")
                edit_sdglen()
            else:
                edit_station_menu()

        def edit_maxtoclear():
            maxtoclear = input("Maximum length that can clear main line at this station: ")
            try:
                sta.clearlen = int(maxtoclear)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a whole number.")
                edit_maxtoclear()
            else:
                sta.canclear = True
                edit_station_menu()

        print("STATION SELECTED: " + sta.name)
        sdg = input("Does this station have a designated passing siding? Y/N")
        if sdg.upper() == "Y":
            edit_sdglen()
        else:
            sta.sdglen = 0
            canclear = input("Can a train clear main track at this station? Y/N")
            if canclear.upper() == "Y":
                edit_maxtoclear()
            else:
                sta.canclear = False
                sta.clearlen = 0
                edit_station_menu()




    print("STATION SELECTED: " + sta.name)
    print("1. Edit MP")
    print("2. Edit name")
    print("3. Edit clearing information")
    print("4. Any other key to return to subdivision")
    choice = input()
    if choice == "1":
        edit_mp()
    elif choice == "2":
        edit_name()
    elif choice == "3":
        edit_clear()
    else:
        display_sub()
```

**My output**

```
SOUTHWARD | ALASKA DIVISION                                   |    NORTHWARD
MP        | STATIONS                          | SDG   | CLEAR | CLEAR LENGTH
29.4      | MOOSE PASS                        | 990   | False | 0
18.4      | CROWN POINT                       | 3704  | False | 0
12.0      | DIVIDE                            | 1920  | False | 0
3.4       | SEWARD                            | 0     | True  | 15000
1. Add Station
2. Edit Station
Any other key to save and return.
2
Enter milepost of station to edit.18.4
STATION SELECTED: CROWN POINT
1. Edit MP
2. Edit name
3. Edit clearing information
4. Any other key to return to subdivision
1
STATION SELECTED: CROWN POINT
Station milepost: 25.4
New milepost is 25.4. Is this correct? Y/N
y
Please enter a whole number.
Enter siding length:
```

First, the program displays the station list as created, then it prompts whether to add a station or edit an existing one. I put in the wrong milepost at `Crown Point`, so I select `edit`, put in the milepost that has been assigned to `Crown Point` and edit it. After asking me whether this is correct the program is supposed to execute the `if-else`-part after the prompt and either
* correct `milepost` in `station` and change itself in `list of mileposts` (necessary for sorting)
* or tell me I didn't change a thing and go back to the menu.
Instead, it's going all the way down to `edit_clear ()` on the `except ValueError`-statement.

Comment: Using recursion is not the way to go here. You might want to read: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Thanks! That will help I think for the individual pieces, but the main problem I'm trying to solve is that even with correct input the code is going to a step that's not even part of the same function, and I can't identify where it is interpreting to do that. The mp editing should have nothing to do with the siding length, and yet the two are somehow linked in a way I haven't been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

> However, edit_mp() is currently taking user input and then jumping into the middle of the edit_clear() function.

No.

You're deep into recursion.

What happens is: edit_station_menu executes edit_clear, which eventually executes edit_station_menu which executes edit_mp

When edit_mp exits, edit_station_menu exits as well (because there's no more things to do):

```
        if choice == "1":
            edit_mp()
        elif choice == "2":
            edit_name()
        elif choice == "3":
            edit_clear()
        else:
            display_sub()
        #edit_station_menu exits here because there's nothing more
```

So now we get when we first executed that particular edit_station_menu - that is, "into the middle of edit_clear() function".

Comment: Hm. So where is it going into the edit_clear() function? It's not supposed to do that unless the user chose 3 on the edit_station_menu() function.

Comment: In the example you posted we don't see your claim that edit_clear is accesses, I only explained how it works for the example you described. Moreover, you edited your code in the meantime, reorganising indentations and removing contents of edit_clear, making your description of the code behaviour even more different than your code!

Comment: Okay, it wasn't you who messed up your code in the question. I'll edit the code back